# Route page to another with button (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a button on home page. When I click on it, I want to go to products page. Can't find solution to that...
Part of code:

```
<Route path="/" exact component={Home}/>
<Route path="/products" component={Products}/>
...
<div>
    <h1>Home Page</h1>
    <button onClick={""}>Go!</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe it's better to use a link? <a href="/products">Go!</a> and make it look like a button you want?

Comment: In a functional component, [`useHistory`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/usehistory), then `onClick={() => history.push('/nextpage')}`. In a class component use [`withRouter`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) and do `onClick={() => this.props.history.push('/nextpage')}`.

Comment: You can use Link in button i.e.<button  component={Link} to="/products">Go!</button>

Comment: Agreed with @vitkarpov, you anchor for navigation, it's much better from semantic prospective and for screen readers

Comment: @vitkarpov I think in my task it's better to make it like a button.

Comment: @RokasAšmena  edited answer plz check accept if helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can navigate using Link component in react in button

```
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
import {Button} from 'reactstrap'

<div>
    <h1>Home Page</h1>
    <Link component={Button} to="/product"> Go! </Link>
</div>
```

or if you do not want to install extra module then this approach better

```
     import {Redirect} from "react-router-dom";

   const onClickProduct = () => {
        return  <Redirect  to="/product" />
      }

  const Home = () => (
    <div>
      <h1>Home Page </h1>
      <button onClick={this.onClickProduct}>Go</button>
    </div>

  )
```

Comment: Im getting "Attribute component is not allowed here" with "to" also.

Comment: I believe you have it [backwards](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link/component-reactcomponent).. Shouldn't it be `<Link component={button} to="/product">...`?

Comment: so it should be:
 import {Link} from "react-router-dom";

<div>
    <h1>Home Page</h1>
    <Link component={button} to="/product"> Go! </Link> ?
Button is not define then.

Comment: You have to use Button component from import {Button} from 'reactstrap';

Comment: Okay, if you want proper button then use another approach I have edited

Comment: ok mate.. :D but one more question, where in my code should I put everything after onClickProduct... My code is: https://prnt.sc/t0anjy

Comment: In Home component just above of div tag

Comment: onClickProduct also?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216012/discussion-between-rokas-asmena-and-himanshu-pandey).

Comment: Did the OP ever say they were using Reactstrap?